# Dynamic Crm: Plugin launch on executing the Fulfill Saleorder only

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

Hy everyone,
 I need actually to make a plugin that is called when the enduser clicks on the "Fulfill" button of the SalesOrder form.
 I looked over the internet and I've seen that is a plugin that is should be launched on update event, which is obviously not good. Any solution?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you for your answare. Actually, I found that I had to put the plugin on the "OrderClose" entity.
I successfully launched the plugin on the preCreation of the plugin. However, I try to close the salesOrder and I failed. Any idea? :)

Answer (score 0):

Fulfill is one of states of order, so you need to add plugin to SetState message and check if statecode that is being set equals to fulfilled (int value = 3)